# What is a good and flexible way to store and count user points?

Tags: php, laravel, performance, count

I would like to credit users for different promotions. For example, when writing an articel, rate an articel ...

I am looking for a flexible solution in which I can adjust the points for the different actions and the total score also changes.

If I save the points in a table, I can not change them afterwards. Like this:

```
$request->user()->points += 10;
    $request->user()->save();
```

How about the performence when I recalculate the points each time? like this:

```
$articlepoints = $user->articles->count();
&votepoints = $user->votes->count();
$totalpoints = $articlepoints*10+$votepoints*5;
```

are there any other options?

Comment: where did this *10 and *5 come from? what are they? are they constants or fetching from database?

Comment: the numbers represent the points in the example

Comment: You could cache the result so that it doesn't have to perform the calculation every time.

Comment: @rockhopper72 How can I cache the result?

Comment: Check out Laravel's docs on caching: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Cache::remember() method if you are trying to minimize counting operations on each load. You just need to decide how often you want to "expire" the cahced value. I am assuming that you would be running this function from within the User model, but you can do it wherever you want:

```
$articlepoints = Cache::remember('articlepoints_'.$this->id, 5, function () {
    return $this->articles->count();
});
```

What this code does is check for the existence of this user's article points in the Cache under the index "articlepoints_userID". The userID is dynamic and a different value would be stored for each user. If that index exists, use it as the value.

If the index doesn't already exist in cache, you would pass into the function where you return the calculated value and store it for 5 minutes. You can do this for each of the values in your equation (votepoints and totalpoints), and use any expiration time you want.

Using this code, you drastically reduce your calls to the count() function. However, you still may be making database calls or disk calls for each of these depending on your cache driver. In order to avoid that type of overhead, you need to look into a different cache driver, such as redis.

Check out the [Laravel Cache docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache) to see all the other cool things you can do with the cache. Learning the cache system is a great way to improve the performance of your Laravel application.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern for this sort of thing is to keep a table to record each event that results in points, and also aggregate the points total in a column either on the user table or some sort of stats table that contains a record for each user. This gives you the ability to keep a record of each event, retroactively recalculate the totals if you change how much each event type is worth, and access the totals (and use them in queries) without having to calculate them each time.

When I do this kind of thing, I use triggers in the database to update the aggregated totals automatically when events are stored so the app logic stays uncluttered. Here's an example that works in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_activity_points` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_username_uk` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `users` (`username`) VALUES ('Bob');
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`) VALUES ('Alice');

CREATE TABLE `activities` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `activities_title_uk` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `activities` (`title`,`points`) VALUES ('Article', 10);
INSERT INTO `activities` (`title`,`points`) VALUES ('Vote', 5);

CREATE TABLE `user_activities` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `activity_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `create_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_activities_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `user_activities_fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`activity_id`) REFERENCES `activities` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_insert_user_activities` //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_user_activities`
  AFTER INSERT
  ON `user_activities`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v_total INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    SET v_total = (SELECT SUM(`activities`.`points`)
                   FROM `user_activities`
                   INNER JOIN `activities` ON `activities`.`id`=`user_activities`.`activity_id`
                   WHERE `user_activities`.`user_id` = NEW.`user_id`);
    UPDATE `users`
    SET `total_activity_points` = v_total
    WHERE `users`.`id` = NEW.`user_id`;
  END;
//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_delete_user_activities` //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_delete_user_activities`
  AFTER DELETE
  ON `user_activities`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v_total INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    SET v_total = (SELECT SUM(`activities`.`points`)
                   FROM `user_activities`
                     INNER JOIN `activities` ON `activities`.`id`=`user_activities`.`activity_id`
                   WHERE `user_activities`.`user_id` = OLD.`user_id`);
    UPDATE `users`
    SET `total_activity_points` = v_total
    WHERE `users`.`id` = OLD.`user_id`;
  END;
//
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO `user_activities` (`user_id`,`activity_id`,`create_date`) VALUES (1,1,NOW());
INSERT INTO `user_activities` (`user_id`,`activity_id`,`create_date`) VALUES (1,2,NOW());
INSERT INTO `user_activities` (`user_id`,`activity_id`,`create_date`) VALUES (2,2,NOW());
INSERT INTO `user_activities` (`user_id`,`activity_id`,`create_date`) VALUES (2,2,NOW());

DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_update_activities` //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_update_activities` AFTER UPDATE ON `activities`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_userId INT(11) UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE v_total INT(11) UNSIGNED;

    DECLARE user_id_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT(`user_activities`.`user_id`) FROM `user_activities` WHERE `user_activities`.`activity_id`=NEW.`id`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    IF NEW.`points` != OLD.`points` THEN
      OPEN user_id_cursor;

      get_user_ids: LOOP
        FETCH user_id_cursor INTO v_userId;
        IF v_finished = 1 THEN
          LEAVE get_user_ids;
        END IF;
        -- recalculate and store scores
        SET v_total = (SELECT SUM(`activities`.`points`)
                       FROM `user_activities`
                         INNER JOIN `activities` ON `activities`.`id`=`user_activities`.`activity_id`
                       WHERE `user_activities`.`user_id` = v_userId);
        UPDATE `users`
        SET `total_activity_points` = v_total
        WHERE `users`.`id` = v_userId;
      END LOOP get_user_ids;

      CLOSE user_id_cursor;
    END IF;
  END;
//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_delete_activities` //
CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete_activities` BEFORE DELETE ON `activities`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_userId INT(11) UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE v_total INT(11) UNSIGNED;

    DECLARE user_id_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT(`user_activities`.`user_id`) FROM `user_activities` WHERE `user_activities`.`activity_id`=OLD.`id`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

    OPEN user_id_cursor;

    get_user_ids: LOOP
      FETCH user_id_cursor INTO v_userId;
      IF v_finished = 1 THEN
        LEAVE get_user_ids;
      END IF;
      -- recalculate and store scores
      SET v_total = (SELECT SUM(`activities`.`points`)
                     FROM `user_activities`
                       INNER JOIN `activities` ON `activities`.`id`=`user_activities`.`activity_id`
                     WHERE `user_activities`.`user_id` = v_userId
                     AND  `user_activities`.`activity_id` != OLD.`id`);
      UPDATE `users`
      SET `total_activity_points` = v_total
      WHERE `users`.`id` = v_userId;
    END LOOP get_user_ids;

    CLOSE user_id_cursor;
  END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

The triggers on the activities table update the totals when the point values change or activities are deleted. The before delete trigger is necessary because MySQL does not run delete triggers on cascaded deletes.